# I have a watch.json file but it doesn't ignore folders

Tags: discord.js

```
{
  "install": {
    "include": [
      "^package\\.json$",
      "^\\.env$"
    ]
  },
  "restart": {
    "exclude": [
      "^public/",
      "^dist/"
    ],
    "include": [
      "\\.js$",
      "\\.json"
    ]
  },
  "throttle": 999999999999
}
```

This currently ignores the index.js.
But I need it to ignore the commands/ folder too, so the folder and all of its commands inside. so that our bot doesn't keep refreshing/restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to add `^commands/` to your `exclude` list under `restart`.